# How to move hosting from mobile.me to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, mobileme

A client of mine had a website hosted on **mobile.me** account.

I received credentials and was prompted to upgrade to **iCloud**.

I asked her to do it on her own machine (there might be some issues with iTunes, sync, etc).

Right now, upon logging to **iCloud** I see only mail / calendar / contacts but NO files / websites... **Any idea is it possible to access previous "WWW" directory from iCloud?**

Thanks for help, if you you need more info put it in the comments...

Answer (score 6):

You will still be able to access the mobile me website and files making the website through June 30th, but iCloud does not offer web hosting or internet-based disk storage. After June 30th you will need to find a different web hosting service.

Longer version here: http://www.apple.com/mobileme/transition.html